# Using a Kalman filter to clean acceleration data

Tags: kalman-filters, sensor

I am collecting acceleration, gyroscope and magnetometer data in all 3 directions. I would like to filter noise from the accelerometer using a Kalman filter. I am not trying to esimate orientatoin or position etc., I just really want to filter the acceleration signals. How should I design this filter?

Comment: A Kalman filter implies more of a design process than a filter structure.  So your question is self-contradictory.  Why don't you tell us what you don't like about your data, and we'll suggest some not-necessarily-Kalman filter to clean it up.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks for the question. I am collecting the accelerometer signals of a drone, so that means the signals already contain base accelerometer noise + mechanical noise due to propellers. Of course, I could filter this out using some low-pass filter. However, I am applying some shaking to the drone on purpose (by adding noise in the control system). The frequency of this shaking is distributed over 1 - 200 Hz, with larger frequencies having more amplitude. Hence, it is very hard to distinguish this "shaking" noise from mechanical and base noise...